# Need help crafting regex string

Tags: regex

I have a block of text that will be populated with tags in a like format:

```
"<$gmngnfj.gif$>"
```

I would like to capture everything in my text block that starts with `<$` and ends with `$>`

I've tried starting with `^<$` but I know that the dollar sign has a meaningful use in regex, so I've gotten stuck. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Do you need to edit your question or are you trying to match everything starting with a . (period)?

Answer (score 3):

Well I'd say look for sth like `<\$(.*)\$>` or to avoid that the regex is too greedy: <\$([^\$]*)\$> .. the result (matching text) would then be available in "\1".

Cheers

Comment: This is perfect, I just need the <$ and $> to be included as well in the matches.

Comment: then use (<\$.*\$>) and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't specified a programming language I just pick python as an example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('<\$(.*?)\$>', 'Hello <$World$>').group(1)
'World'
```

Here is another example (in ruby) in an nice online regex testing tool:

- http://rubular.com/r/3RDeg3HGSf

Comment: I think it's better to use .*? to avoid catching <$gmngnfj.gif$>kjhkjh$> for example. +1 after edit :)